# Merge with conflicts in TFS

Tags: tfs, version-control, merge, conflict, harvest-scm

I have recently started to work as a build manager. We are using TFS here. Whenever I move code from one branch to another, I have to work with developers to resolve conflicts because I have no idea of what code they are writing.
Is there a way that I can merge changes and those conflicts remain in TFS and then the developers resolve them and check in the resolved files?

When I used to work as a developer, we used CA SCM Harvest for source control where the build managers just use to merge the code with conflicts and we developers used to resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

Any merges will be isolated to your account.  Make the developers merge the branches instead.

We stopped using branches and merging 2 years ago.  All the developers use a single main branch and its so much easier.  But you have to learn to be [Release Ready](http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/16/are-you-release-ready/).